# Maximal disjoint sets in a list

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Given $A = [[4, 10, 14], [5, 13, 14], [2, 7, 13], [0, 2, 12], [2, 4, 11], [3, 5, 11], [3, 7, 10], [6, 9, 10], [0, 1, 3]]$ is a list of sets. I want to find the maximum number of sets from the list which are disjoint. (By disjoint, I mean that if I have selected $[4,10,14]$ then I cannot select $[5,13,14]$ since it contains $14$ which I had already chosen in the previous set.

The answer for this particular problem would be 4, as I can choose $[0,1,3], [6, 9, 10],[2, 4, 11],[5, 13, 14]$

I tried the greedy approach but it does not seem to be optimal for all cases. Any suggestions on what algorithms/approaches I can try out ?

Comment: I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41070077) on StackOverflow is helpful. (found by googling the title)

Comment: @GregMartin that answer is mistaken I think, they assume consecutive numbers in each set (or that the sets are intervals?). The other answer looks plausible though.

Comment: I believe I linked to the Peter de Rivaz answer (see especially its second paragraph), which is the one I'm guessing you find plausible.

Comment: I was kind of thinking that it was an NP-complete problem, but link in the below answer by @Hanssen clears this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *Maximum Disjoint Set* problem is NP-complete.

This was [shown at CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/85400/show-that-maximum-disjoint-set-problem-is-np-complete).

Comment: I guess that would have been a better forum to post this! Thanks for the reference!